# Fixing code: Finding all calls to the ordinal method of an enum

Tags: java, eclipse, enums

I have some poorly written code that clearly violates [Effective Java 31](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PR10&ots=yYHjJgu1Q3&dq=effective%20java%20item%2031&pg=PA158#v=onepage&q&f=false).

I'm trying to fix it by adding an instance field with a getter but I am having a really hard time finding all the references to the `.ordinal()` method on the enum. Doing an Eclipse call hierarchy on `.ordinal()` gets me all references to that method on any enum. There are hundreds of examples of this bad practice in this code base and I can't fix all of them; I just want to fix it for this one enum.

Is there any way in Eclipse, or with another tool, to find all references to `MyEnum.ordinal()`?

Answer (score 3):

I would first find all references to `MyEnum` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, and from those references, manually see which ones invoke `MyEnum#ordinal()`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, No, "*Doing an eclipse call hierarchy on .ordinal() gets me all references to that method on any enum*" What I'm suggesting is finding all references to `MyEnum` and then inspecting each reference for invocation of `ordinal`.

Comment: Still gets me 128 reference to this enum.  Too large to do actually go through them all.  I basically want the intersection of these two things.

Comment: @MattKelly, But I'm sure 128 references is still a lot less than your original query returned ;)

Answer (score 2):

Delete the Enum and take note of all of the errors that reference ordinal() in the IDE error view.

Comment: I wouldn't call it ugly... your solution provides a tree, mine provides a list... unorthodox, sure, but every bit as elegant and simple.